# Why is this JSONP url written like this?

Tags: cors, jsonp

Now I am attempting to do a random quote generator challenge from freecodecamp.
However, I have been having a lot of trouble to get the quotes from the site 
http://api.forismatic.com due to CORS ... then I stumbled upon someone's solution but I don't understand why he has included a query `jsonp=?` at the end of the url.

He created:

```
// Random Quote Generator
var url = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?";
```

I follow everything except for the `jsonp=?` at the end ... 
I know there has to be a callback and I tried to replace it with `callback=?`
but then got an error:

```
"Refuse to execute script from (data resource) because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the docs at http://forismatic.com/en/api/:

> ***jsonp=<string>*** — callback function name, used for jsonp format only

So they just have a `jsonp` param where for exactly the same thing other APIs use `callback`.

And so given `method=getQuote&key=457653&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?`, a literal "`?`" is what the API will return as the callback function name:

```
$ curl "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?"

?({"quoteText":"I have done my best: that is about all the philosophy of living one needs.","quoteAuthor":"Lin-yutang","senderName":"","senderLink":"","quoteLink":"http://forismatic.com/en/475d78775d/"})
```

In other words, there’s nothing magic about the parameter name "`callback`"—there’s no standard which mandates that param name must be used, so any API provider can choose to use any name they want—as forismatic.com chooses to for their API.

Comment: but I wonder how the coder knew that "?" was the name of the callback function as it didn't say that on the forismatic site .... there was an example but w/ a diff function name.        
and what is "$ curl" ? I tried to google, a tool for command line to transfer data ?

Comment: Yeah `?` seems a strange choice for a function name